# Spark submit on Yarn failing with error "Permission mismatch for caller"

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to submit my spark job to yarn but it keep on failing with the message:

```
[2019-05-13 14:13:18.281]Application application_1557517779491_0093 initialization failed (exitCode=20) with output: main : command provided 0
main : run as user is yogesh
main : requested yarn user is yogesh
Permission mismatch for /data/hadoop/yarn/local for caller uid: 0, owner uid: 1007.
Couldn't get userdir directory for yogesh.
```

I have tried to update the permission of the mentioned directory but its still failing.